# NoClassDefFound Error after adding jdom to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, noclassdeffounderror, jdom

I've added the jdom jar to my Servlet (`BuildPath > Configure Buildpath > Add External Jar`). Since, my Servlet is not working anymore, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/selection_jsp (wrong name: org/apache/jsp/Selection_jsp)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Added the jdom jar to WEB-INF/lib and deleted the jar from the build path.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is amazingly simple:

- redeploy the application.

if it doesn't work,

- clear AS cache;
- restart AS.

this should be (sort of) a caching problem .